# libncurses: non-blocking STDIN + select on socket

Tags: c, sockets, select, curses

I'm using `select` to do non-blocking reads from a socket and STDIN. In pseudo-code:

```
loop
  readable = select(socket, STDIN)
  foreach input in readable
    if input == STDIN
      handle_keyboard_input(read(STDIN))
    else
      handle_socket_input(read(socket))
```

The above works great. But now I'd like to start using libncurses to build a more sophisticated text-based UI. (I'll probably have two windows: A large log window and a smaller one for the prompt.)

Presumably, the socket handling will remain the same. But I'm unclear on how libncurses abstracts away STDIN. What is the correct idiom for doing non-blocking reads in a libncurses window?

In truth this is in Ruby, but I'm just using thin wrappers around the C APIs, so I felt this was more appropriately tagged as a C problem.

Comment: There's nothing special. Just add `STDIN_FILENO` to your select set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, `ncurses` only reads from its input stream when you call an input function such as `getch`. So to that extent, `ncurses` doesn't abstract away anything; all it does is to associates two file descriptors, one for input and one for output, with each `SCREEN`. See `man newterm` for details.

If you call `nodelay` or use `timeout/wtimeout` to set a timeout of 0, then `getch` will immediately return an error if there is no pending input for the corresponding window. That's basically all you need to write asynchronous input handling (as far as `ncurses` is concerned.) If you want to use a `select` loop, you'll need to deal with the mechanics of scheduling background tasks, etc. `ncurses` has rudimentary support for multi-threaded applications if you want to go that route.

Comment: Would there be any problem with using `select` for the socket and `getch` for STDIN within the same loop?

Comment: @Jarrett: No, that would be fine, particularly if you have a single-threaded event loop. The problem might come if you try to do input in one thread and screen display in another thread, since `getch` normally does some screen display, including a `refresh`.